# Test Verilog FSM for state with no reset

Tags: verilog, state-machines, test, testbench

My professor gave us several Verilog test files to write Verilog test benches for. In the test bench, we're supposed to initialize the state to 0, apply random inputs, and check to see if we have reached the target state within x amount of cycles. However, none of these Verilog files have an input for reset and most are too large to create a truth table for. So, how am I supposed to initialize and know what state the FSM is in based on IO?

Here is one of the simplest examples:

```
module ex1(clock,A,Y);
input clock;
input A;
output Y;
reg S0,S1;
wire X1,NS0,NS1;
and g0(X1,S0,S1);
and g1(NS1,A,X1);
not g2(NS0,X1);
and g3(Y,A,X1);
always @(posedge clock) begin
S1<=NS1;
S0<=NS0;
end
endmodule
//State:11
```

You can see the target state is left as a comment on the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You really have no alternative but to do some kind of analysis of the next state logic. This might be a full-blown truth table but you might also be clever about it. For example, I can see that if input A is low then NS1 must be low. So now I know how to make S1 go low...maybe I can use that, plus some value of A, to set the value of S0?

Answer (score 0):

Use the force... no really, Verilog has a `force` operator that can put an initial value on a sequential element. It has a `release` statement to stop the forcing action.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355714/what-are-the-uses-of-force-release-statements

You can use this to initialize your FSM to all the possible startup states, then observe how many cycles it takes to get to a legal state.

In this case, based on the exercise, you only need to use a single force-release pair on S1/S0 at the beginning of the sim, then test with your combinations of inputs. But once you've done that, it would not be hard to expand your testbench to include all the possible cases of S1/S0.